# How to add subtitle

Tags: r

I am attempting to add titles to my plot. The main title is working, but I cannot seem to get the subtitle to work. I am shooting for the subtitle to be the same as the caption in ggplot2 (in the lower right hand corner). Here is my code:

called_strike_plot(PData, "2022 Probability of Called Strike", sub = "Baseball Savant")

I am receiving an error message of:
Error in called_strike_plot(PData, "2022 Probability of Called Strike",  :
unused argument (sub = "Baseball Savant")

Comment: Can you please make your issue reproducible by indicating the packages used and providing a usable data snippet and an example of the problematic plot? This will make the question more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code for [`called_strike_plot()`](https://rdrr.io/github/bayesball/CalledStrike/src/R/called_strike_plot.R), the function calls `geom_tile()` which will likely accept additional ggplot2 commands, i.e.

```r
called_strike_plot(PData, "2022 Probability of Called Strike") +
  labs(subtitle = "Baseball Savant")
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Ah, yes thank you! Did not realize ggplot2 commands would've worked